# Как дописать массив php

Tags: массивы, ajax, php

Всем привет, столкнулся с проблемой у меня AJAX запрос передает в обработчик ID:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="dels('.$reblogs['blog_id'].');">
```

Этот ID нужно записать в массив. И таких инпутов много.

```
function dels(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/ajax/test5.php',
        data: {
            test: id
        },
        success: function(data) {
            var x = id;
            $('.results152d').html(data);
        }
    })
}
```

Вот, собственно, AJAX. Не могу понять, как можно дописывать массив. Подскажите плз, он передает один параметр, но он разный `$_POST['test']`

Comment: @Dminko93, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

ajax запрос — это как открыть страницу: один запрос — одна страница, один раз php скрипт отработал. Если вам нужен в php массив состояний всех чекбоксов, нужно их все разом передать в одном ajax запросе. Дайте каждому чекбоксу имя `name="..."` и вместо `data: ...` как-то так:

```
data: $('input[type="checkbox"]').serialize(),
```

Тогда в сервер уйдут все включённые чекбоксы как пары "имяПоля=on". [**Пример.**](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/ctegL32o/)

Второй момент, не пишите в каждом input'е "onclick" — вешайте обработчики событий тем же jQuery:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function(e){ что делать });
```